# Create a form into Polymer - (Google App Engine & Python)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, polymer

I'm building a small app on Google App Engine using Polymer, I' ve a little menu and other cool things but I' m a little bit confused about a simple step, I' d like to give some input to the app, these variables will be saved into the datastore and retrieved in other pages.

How have I to build the form? I' ll try to be more specific, in the different pages I' d like to insert different  so user will make a numeric choice and pressing a button that values will be sent to the server. I' m googling since yesterday and i found different answers.

There' s someone could give me a link to specific lesson that talks about interaction with Polymer or the right manner to do this?

Comment: it's just a normal form. When you submit it it will go to a POST handler, that you will write, that will extract the data from the form. See https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html That you are using polymer is irrelevant really.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [ajax-form](http://ajax-form.raynicholus.com/components/ajax-form/).

**Installation**

`bower install ajax-form` in your commandline.

**Using it**

`<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/ajax-form/ajax-form.html">`

Please enter the correct path here. I'm assuming you're structuring your elements like `root/elements/element-name/element-name.html`

**Creating a form**

```
<form is="ajax-form" action="/api/user/create" method="post">
    <label>Enter your name: <input type="text" name="full_name"></label>
</form>
```

**Receiving the call on the server**

`import webapp2`

```
class CreateUserHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):  # not needed (yet), you can decide to leave this function out
        pass

    def post(self):
        print(self.request.get('full_name'))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/api/user/create', CreateUserHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i posted this answer on another post just a second ago but will paste it here as well.

to do a form i first make a polymer element for this example i will call it "my-form".  in that element we will make a created function that will set up our object we are sending to the server. below is a simple version with only 1 input field but should give you a idea how it works.

```
<polymer-element name="my-form">
  <template>
    <div id="invalid">
      <paper-input-decorator
        id="check"
        floatinglabel
        error="Error!!!"
        label="LABEL">
        <input is="core-input" id="data" required committedValue="{{item.firstItem}}" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+$">
      </paper-input-decorator>
      <br>
      <paper-button
        on-tap="{{checkData}}"
        raised>
        Save
      </paper-button>
    </div>
    <core-ajax
      id="ajax"
      auto="false"
      method="POST"
      url="URL"
      handleas="json"
      params='{{item}}'
      response="{{response}}">
    </core-ajax>
    <paper-toast id="toast"></paper-toast>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-form', {
      created: function () {
        // sets up the object 
        this.item = {}; 
      },
      checkData: function () {
          // this function will check data of all inputs in the invalid div to make sure it matches data type and pattern
          var $d = this.$.invalid.querySelectorAll('paper-input-decorator'),
            that = this;
          Array.prototype.forEach.call($d, function (d) {
            d.isInvalid = !d.querySelector('input').validity.valid;
          });
          // the timeout gives time to mark as invalid before checking 
          setTimeout(function () {
            // for each input you are checking you will need another variable and also to add the check to the following if statment
            var invalid = that.$.check.classList.contains("invalid");

            if (!invalid) {
               that.$.ajax.go();
            }
          }, 100);
      },
      responseChanged: function () {
        // do something on response i like to use a paper-toast here alerting the user the data has been accepted or rejected
         this.$.toast.text = response;
         this.$.toast.show();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

same example on plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/xDJK6BJOmh8Bd0FJGEVk?p=preview